# Change size of legend in core plot?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-plot

I have a pie graph with a corresponding legend. How do I change the size of the legend box? (make everything including the text, colour boxes and frame smaller).

Note I am building an application for OSX not iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just set a smaller text style of the `CPTLegend`, everything will be resized as requested. So for your `CPTGraph` you are going to want to do:

```
CPMutableTTextStyle *mySmallerTextStyle = [[[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
[textStyle setFontName:fontName];
[textStyle setColor:color];

//This is the important property for your needs
[textStyle setFontSize:5];

//Set this up with your graph
[graph setLegend:[CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph]];
[[graph legend] setTextStyle:(CPTTextStyle *)mySmallerTextStyle];
```

There is a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/coreplot-discuss/LMEtRt1b4zI/discussion) regarding this on the CorePlot forum.